# Copying DLL to server vs Visual Studio site publish

Tags: visual-studio, iis, dll

ASP.net MVC (v5.2.7) solution with a project, separate from the web project, that compiles to dll that gets copied to the /bin directory on the web server during site publish. That dll will modify the user's UI based on class settings.  If I change the class and do a whole site publish, I get the UI change I expect.

However, if I compile the dll's project in the solution, take the resulting DLL and copy it to the web server /bin directory, I never see the UI change.  I can see the date/time stamp is different.  The version# has incremented.  I've stopped/started the app pool. I've stopped/started the site. I've stopped and started IIS.  I've closed the browser. I've used a different browser.  But when copying that single dll by hand and dropping it in the site's /bin folder on the server, I never see the UI change I expect.  When I do a full site publish, I see the change I expect.

What is msbuild and msdeploy doing that I am not?

Comment: You have no way of knowing what MSbuild does to all files when you publish your app. But asp.net applications do not support copying and pasting individual dll files into IIS. And in the mvc application, the UI changes in the view layer not only modify the dll, but also need to update the cshtml file in the view folder. The View folder also has web.config to configure the view layer information.

Comment: Depending on your publishing settings, the project can be precompiled, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb398860(v=vs.100) which actually works differently in a lot of ways. So if you really want to learn what MSBuild does, enable bin log and see for yourself, https://msbuildlog.com